# StringBuffer and appender method

Tags: java, stringbuffer, appender

I have to make a program that add `Strings` to each other as many as argument in method says. Program is not working and i dont know why. Thanks for your time. The problem is in the `main` in `ap.append(" ma kota", 3).append( " i psa", 2);`. I cant make changes to the main.

```
public class Appender {
    private StringBuffer sb;

    public Appender(){
        sb = new StringBuffer();
    }

    public Appender(String s){
        sb = new StringBuffer(s);
    }

    public StringBuffer append(String str, int n) {
        while(n > 0){
            sb.append(str);
            n--;
        }
        return sb;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = sb.toString();
        return "" + s;
    }
}
```

And this is my main :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Appender ap = new Appender("Ala");
        ap.append(" ma kota", 3).append( " i psa", 2);
        System.out.println(ap);
        ap.append(" ojej", 3);
        System.out.println(ap);
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: do you understand this right: you have to append str n-times to your **Appender** ? 
  so as example: ap.append("hi", 3) will make "hihihi" ?

Comment: you get print only "Ala" ? right ?

Comment: Aside: unless you have a specific reason to use `StringBuffer` you should probably be using `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public StringBuffer append(String str, int n) {
    while(n > 0){
        sb.append(str);
        n--;
    }
    return sb;
}
```

should change to

```
public Appender append(String str, int n) {
    while(n > 0){
        sb.append(str);
        n--;
    }
    return this;
}
```

because StringBuffer does not have method append(String s, int n)

Answer (score 2):

The `append(String appended, int n)` method belongs to `Appender`, not `StringBuilder` so you have to return it, instead of the `sb`

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
         Appender ap = new Appender("Ala");
        ap.append(" ma kota", 3).append( " i psa", 2);
        System.out.println(ap);
        ap.append(" ojej", 3);
        System.out.println(ap);
     }
     public static class Appender {
        private StringBuffer sb;

        public Appender(){
            sb = new StringBuffer();
        }

        public Appender(String s){
            sb = new StringBuffer(s);
        }

        public Appender append(String str, int n) {
            while(n > 0){
                sb.append(str);
                n--;
            }
            return this;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return sb.toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return this(current object) from `com.test.FunPrime.Appender.append(String, int)`

like

```
public Appender append(String str, int n) {
        while(n > 0){
            sb.append(str);
            n--;
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils#repeat` for this.

For example repeat for 5 times:

> String result = StringUtils.repeat("repeat this string", ", ", 5);

The version without the second argument (the separator ", ") is also available.